# Is it possible to use vite with Nuxt.js for fast reloading?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite

According to this documentation https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#vite, we can use vite with Vue.js for fast reloading.

I'm now switching to Nuxt.js and I'm wondering if it is possible to use vite with Nuxt.js.

I did not find an official way to do that, but it there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you **will** be able to use Vite with Nuxt once it's migrated to Nuxt 3 (with Vue3 backed in).

Right now, it's still on Webpack4 as of right now but you pretty much follow this [github thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7362#issuecomment-764921573) for futher updates. So far, the core team will unleash the possibility to interchangeably choose between Webpack and Vite.

Also, I can suggest that you check this week's JS World Conference because @atinux (Sebastien Chopin) [will give a talk](https://frontenddeveloperlove.com/program/#d-5-s-7__) about Nuxt. So who knows, Nuxt3 maybe ?

[image]